# How to replace "N", "S", "E", "W" in grid in ArcGIS Pro layout

Tags: arcgis-pro, layouts

I want to replace N, S, E, W in layout in ArcGIS Pro with cardinal direction in Bahasa Indonesia. Is it possible to change that automatically without replace it manually one by one?

Comment: Are you talking about the northline?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't have a Bahasa language pack, and you are using Dynamic Text for labeling, turn off the showDirections and add the Bahasa as a suffix
for Instance

```
<dyn type="grid" units="dms" decimalPlaces="0" showDirections="False" showZeroMinutes="False" showZeroSeconds="False"/> Timur
```

[image]